# Visual Studio Designer: Nullable Object must have a value

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I am getting this in Visual Studio Designer:

```
Nullable object must have a value.
```

And the cryptic stack trace:

```
at System.ComponentModel.ReflectPropertyDescriptor.SetValue(Object component, Object value)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.VsTargetFrameworkPropertyDescriptor.SetValue(Object component, Object value)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializePropertyAssignStatement(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeAssignStatement statement, CodePropertyReferenceExpression propertyReferenceEx, Boolean reportError)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeAssignStatement(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeAssignStatement statement)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeStatement(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeStatement statement)
```

Ideas on how to find the problem?

Comment: Show your code please..

Comment: The whole designer code? It's massive!

Comment: Any tips on what I should look for in the Designer code?

Comment: There has to be some more context to the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem. In the .Designer.vb, a nullable property of a control was set by the VS2010 Designer to Nothing:

```
        '
        'cmbInputPostingDate
        '
        Me.cmbInputPostingDate.AllowUserToType = True
        Me.cmbInputPostingDate.DateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
        Me.cmbInputPostingDate.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(79, 41)
        Me.cmbInputPostingDate.Name = "cmbInputPostingDate"
        Me.cmbInputPostingDate.ReadOnly = False
        Me.cmbInputPostingDate.SelectionLength = 0
        Me.cmbInputPostingDate.SelectionStart = 0
        Me.cmbInputPostingDate.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(115, 21)
        Me.cmbInputPostingDate.TabIndex = 255
        Me.cmbInputPostingDate.TextAlign = System.Windows.Forms.HorizontalAlignment.Left
        Me.cmbInputPostingDate.Value = Nothing
```

The last line was the culprit - don't ask how I found it - was pure luck. In that control the .Value was defined as follows:

```
 Public Property Value() As Date?
        Get
            Return mValue
        End Get
        Set(ByVal val As Date?)
            mValue = val
            Me.Text = SH.VBFormat(CDate(val), Me.mDateFormat)
        End Set
    End Property
```

Adding the following attribute to the property above:

```
 [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
```

and removing all the lines that the VS2010 Designer put in fixes this problem. Really wish VS Designer would point to a line. The only way I found this was looking at the TFS history for this file and seeing who added what recently.

Comment: a TypeConverter could also fix it if you needed the prop value to be persisted...or instead of Nothing/Nullable return Date.MinDate

Comment: +1. VS designer has all sorts of issues. Be prepared for more. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too.  I had been adding and deleting a lot of items from a ribbon bar in my app.  Ribbon bars can contain a lot of child elements.  However, some of the child elements I had created in the past I had removed from the ribbon but they were still being created in the designer file.  So I identified and deleted every element that was no longer in my ribbon and that fixed the problem.

TLDR: delete orphaned controls.